# Best practice for handle connections/queries

Tags: c#, .net

Question about C# best practices. I have a class that iterates over 5000 Objects and makes a call to the back end for each of those objects:

**Class running loop:**

```
for(Object x in objects) //5000
{
   nonStaticObject.callThisMethod(x.id);
}
```

**DAL layer:**

```
ReturnObject x = null;
using(SQLConnection...)
{
    using(SQLCommand...)
    {
         // run something here
         // if found, instantiate object x
    }
}
```

I did some profiling because of some high CPU generated from my code (parallel for loops) and the hotspots appear to be (and rightfully so) all the calls I'm making to the database. And because these calls are very frequent, I had some questions.

In my mind, my thought is that I should reuse the connection if possible. Is that best practice? I want to allow the code to handle connection disposing (using the using keyword), how do I set up a connection effectively with this strategy that is usable for all 5000 calls? Should I be creating a connection every call to that method like I am now? (I read somewhere that the ADO connection pool reuses connections automatically, so maybe this is already done in the background?).

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is it the actual calls to the DB, or some code near them? Try .NET profiler on one side, then SQL profiler, and compare the results. In my experience, when working with DB, the most time is spent **waiting** for results. That's why it helps to combine multiple queries into one.

Comment: The SQL Profiler doesn't indicate anything of worry. Indexes in place are effective and quick. I think it's because of the sheer number of connections I'm making? All 5000 get processed in 30 seconds, so that's 5000 connection requests in short order (if that matters).

Comment: Your connections don't have to be release that often. As long as you are using them, you can let it open. You have to think in Transactions, not connections. But the issue might be in the iteration itself. I still can't figure it out how does the upper code relates to the code bellow.

Comment: It would help if you included more code, cause right now your explanation is rather abstract for us to give any concrete advice (beside what @Habib already mentioned in the answer below). Maybe try to come up with a analogy to explain your process in simple terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Usually,* with respect to database connections, the policy should be open as late as possible and close as early as possible. So lets say if you have a single statement/query to execute then open the connection before executing the query and close your connection after that.

**But**, in your case you are executing 5000 queries in a loop, so there is no point in opening/closing the connection 5000 times. Instead utilize the single connection and execute all your queries.

Also, opening and closing connection just returns the connection to .Net connection pool. If there is already an open connection then opening a connection using `Conn.Open();` would return *that* opened connection from the connection pool. See: [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Creating database connections - Do it once or for each query?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142065/creating-database-connections-do-it-once-or-for-each-query)

Comment: So in my case, where I have a DAL object that uses a method to generate a request to the DB, how would I use connection pooling to open a connection prior to the 5000 calls? Normally, I use the using() {...} process to allow for this to happen (which I suspect I couldn't do in my current setup). And thank you for the answer :)

Comment: @user2124871, pass your collection to a method in DAL, have your connection in `using` statement and inside that, execute your loop, so for each item same connection would be used.

Comment: OK that's what I figured. Thanks again for the tip.